# Exporting excel spreedsheet to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Is there a proper way to export an Excel spreadsheet into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, and there are numerous methods to do so. Start with [googling how to use the SSMS Import utility](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/). Then once you are full of hate for the excel driver, you can pursue other methods like excel XML, OPENQUERY or BULKINSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the database you want to import/export to, click Tasks, then Import Data/Export Data, then follow the wizard that pops up, it's pretty straight forward from there.

[image: screenshot]